# How to encrypt a folder using golang

Tags: linux, go, encryption

I want to encrypt a folder in golang, but I have no idea how to go about it. All I found on the internet are examples of encrypting a file, not a folder..

Thanks!

Comment: You need to turn the directory into a file first, for example `tar` or `tar.gz`. Then you can encrypt the file.

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter, and what help do you need?

Answer (score 3):

Encryption is a mechanism for encoding a byte stream in such a way that the original byte stream cannot be deciphered by a reader without the key.

A folder is a file system construct.

You cannot encrypt a file system construct; only a byte stream. In order to "encrypt a folder", you can do one of two things:

- Encrypt each file within the folder separately
- Convert the folder into a single file (e.g. TAR) and encrypt that

Which is preferable depends on your specific needs, but these are the available options. This is why you cannot find examples of encrypting a folder; as a concept, it is technically infeasible.